# What is this tool called?

Tags: tools

I am at a loss trying to figure out what this tool is, hopefully this is being asked in the right place.

The images are screen shots from a video, hopefully they are enough.

It is quite small, perhaps about 15cm on each side.  It appears to do small position adjustments using the 2 silver dials on each side.  The small oval plate on top I think tilts.

The tool is being used in the video to screen print small items where positioning is critical.

I hope this is enough information.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't a woodworking tool (so is off-topic for this SE and the Question will be closed in due course). What the pictures show I think is a type of two-axis clamp, possibly with a custom top panel. Similar things of various designs are used in metalworking for milling operations, allowing very precise X, Y adjustments to position the workpiece relative to the cutter head.

Answer (score 1):

This is an "X-Y table" or a "milling table".  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Y_table) is the Wikipedia entry about them.

Graphus's comment is correct, this is not typically used in woodworking (so I will vote to close this question, sorry).  The most common application is in a machinist's mill.

Answer (score 1):

This is what appears to be a shop-made "X-Y Table (perhaps "stage")" similar to those used in a *toolmakers microscope*. In this situation, moving the object of study is preferred over moving the lens assembly. In more elaborate models, precision measurements can be made by reading the micrometers used for x and y-axis positioning and aligning features with a reticule (hairline) seen through the lens.

A somewhat more elaborate version can be seen here: [Toolmakers Microscope](https://www.microscopeworld.com/p-1778-toolmakers-microscope.aspx).

This question might be a candidate for Engineering StackOverflow, since such devices would commonly be used in a mechanical engineering prototyping shop and manufacturing tool-rooms.